# PHP Unit Testing: How can we pass multiple parameters while mocking a method?

Tags: php, unit-testing

```
    $observer = $this->getMockBuilder('Apps_Sample_DataHandler')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->disableOriginalClone()
            ->disableArgumentCloning()
            ->getMock();

    $observer->method('getSampleData')
         ->will($this->returnCallback('mockTestCall'));


    $this->assertEquals('foo', $observer->getSampleData());
```

Here we are trying mock the method 'getSampleData' with 'mockTestCall'.

**We wanted to know how we can pass a parameter to the method 'mockTestCall'.**

Definition for the method 'mockTestCall' is given below:

```
public function mockTestCall($arg1){
    return $arg1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP >= 5.4:

```
$observer->method('getSampleData')
    ->will($this->returnCallback(
        function() {
            $this->mockTestCall('arg1_value');
        }
    ));
```

For PHP 5.3:

```
$that = $this;
$observer->method('getSampleData')
    ->will($this->returnCallback(
        function() use($that) {
            $that->mockTestCall('arg1_value');
        }
    ));
```